# Prolog recursively multiply

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to multiply two numbers in Prolog recursively i.e. `3*4 = 3+3+3+3 = 12`.

My code is :

```
mult(0,Y,Y).
mult(X,Y,Z) :- 
    NewX is X-1, 
    Z is Y + mult(NewX,Y,Z).
```

but I keep either in an infinite loop or being told `mult` is not a function.

Comment: Prolog has *no* functions, it has predicates, so you can not do such thing as `X is A + pred(Y)`. Yes `is/2` interpretes certain functors, but the above is *not* how it is supposed to work.

Comment: So what would be the way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you here constructed is a *predicate*. A predicate is *not* the same as a function in computer science, you can not write `A is B + some_pred(C)`, or at least not as far as I know in ISO Prolog, and definitely not without adding some extra logic.

In order to pass values, one uses variables. We can thus *call* the `mult/3` predicate recursively, and use a variable that will be *unified* with the result. We can then perform arithmetic with it, like:

```
mult(0, _, 0).
mult(X, Y, Z) :-
    X1 is X - 1,
    mult(X1, Y, Z1),
    Z is Y + Z1.
```

Note that you can *not* reassign a (different) value to a variable. So if, like you did in the question, use `Z` twice, then given `Y` is not `0`, this will fail.

The above is however still not sufficient, since it will produce a result, but then get stuck in an infinite loop since if it calls (eventually) `mult(0, 4, Z)` (`4` is here just a value), there are two ways to resolve this: with the base case, and with the recursive case.

We thus need a "guard" for the second case, like:

```
mult(0, _, 0).
mult(X, Y, Z) :-
    X > 0,
    X1 is X - 1,
    mult(X1, Y, Z1),
    Z is Y + Z1.
```

We then obtain for example:

```
?- mult(14, 25, Z).
Z = 350 ;
false.
```

One can improve the speed of this `mult/3` predicate by implementing a version with an *accumulator*. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: So it can be improved with an accumulator, what exactly is one?

Comment: "What you here define a predicate." -- not sure that makes sense as a sentence. Maybe you meant "what you have is a predicate"?

Comment: Separately, `14 * 25` is 350 not 375. I think `mult(0, Y, Y)` should be `mult(0, _, 0)`.

Comment: @Dunes: yes... Unfortunately I did not check the semantics :)

Comment: I vaguely recall there was a time when, as an extension, SWI-Prolog would allow you to declare mathematical functions for the right side of `is/2`, but that time is long past and it is not ISO to be able to do so.

Comment: I figured the mult(0, Y, Y) problem out. @WillemVanOnsem thank you, if I were to add a '!' before the 'Z is Y + Z1' would it remove the false that it returns also?

Comment: @EllisThompson: yes, like `mult(0, _, Y) :- !`. Although if you later would generalize the predicate to make it multidirecitonal, this can have unwanted side-effects.

Comment: multidirectional being?

Comment: @DanielLyons: yes, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854812/implementing-user-defined-arithmetic-functions) it is - given of course the answer is correct, but I'm quite confident, not standardized.

Comment: @EllisThompson: that you can later query for `mult(X, 3, 15)` for example to obtian `X=5`. In Prolog, most predicates can be queried in several directions. For example `length(L, N)` can be used to query for the length of a list (like `length([1,4], N)`), but also validate the length (`length([1,4], 2)`) or generate a list of length 2 (`length(L, 2)`), or enumerate over lists with different lengths (`length(L, N)`).